# how to change textbox value after a textbox textchanged event?

Tags: c#

I have two text box `Textbox1` and `Textbox2` . I want to bring some values in textbox2 as per the textbox1 value. I have a query

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     string str="select TimeIn from Employee where Date='"+txtdate.text+"'";
     Sqldatreader dr=conn.query(str);
     if(dr.Read())
     {
     Textbox2.text=dr[0].Tostring();
     }
   }
```

Comment: How about `Textbox2.Text = Textbox1.Text`?

Comment: You should specify whether you are using, winforms/WPF/Webforms etc., to do this.

Comment: In WPF you can easily do this with data binding.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Soner Gönül, Sorry see my updated question

Comment: You haven't told us what is not working.

Comment: An information beside: If you want to fire a SQL-Statement, don't directly fill in the txtDate.Text into the `WHERE`-clause of your statement. This is extremely vulnerable for SQL-Injection. You should take a look at SQL-Parameters (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Enigmativity, I am not getting TimeIn in my textbox2 after I enter  date in textbox1

Comment: @Tomtom, its just for a sample. even though its not working..in place of textbox if it was a dropown means its ok after page refresh it fills the value but what about in the case of text box. That I want know

Comment: Can you check that the `TextBox1.TextChanged` event is firing by putting `Textbox2.text = "Hello";` at the start of the `TextBox1_TextChanged` method?

Comment: @Enigmativity, The above mentioned query works when page getting refresh or after button click. Not getting when I type date

Comment: @BrunoBlane - So when you added the `Textbox2.text = "Hello";` code **and** type in the date field then `Textbox2` gets updated to `"Hello"`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the property `AutoPostBack= True` for `TextBox1` and then do it as

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string SelectCustomerBalance = "Select cbalance FROM customer where cname = '" +  
                               searchLookUpEdit1.Text + "'";

con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SelectCustomerBalance, con);
SqlDataReader datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// con.Close();
if (datareader.Read())
  {
     txtcustomercurrentBlnc.Text = datareader["cbalance"].ToString();
  }
```