# How to fill a textbox by using another textbox textchanged event?

Tags: c#

I have already asked this question. But I did not get a proper answer thats why I am asking same question in more detail way.
I have a textbox text changed event .That is

```
 protected void txtbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string str = "select TimeIn from MusterRoll where EmpCode='" + txtbox1.Text + "'";
        SqlDataReader dr=conn.query(str);
        if(dr.Read())
        {
            txtbox2.Text=dr[0].ToString();
        }
      }
```

My issue is when I enter textbox1(EmpCode) textbox2 is not filling. Its fills only when I click on submit button(fills only page getting refreshed). But I want to fill texbox2  on the spot itself when I enter textbox1 value...eg(if I write this query in a dropdownlist selectedindexchanged event it will work properly. The same way I want work this with this texchanged event). help me

Comment: show textbox code if it is in asp.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change textbox value after a textbox textchanged event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143841/how-to-change-textbox-value-after-a-textbox-textchanged-event)

Comment: **EDIT** your previous question to make it more clear, don't ask a duplicate.

Comment: insted of giving answer for my question simply downvoating my question???

Comment: @J. Steen, I edited my question but i did not a an answer

Comment: You certainly didn't include all this information in the old question. Did you consider that might be the reason you didn't get the answer you wanted? Be clear. Be concise. Explain your problem in enough detail that anyone can understand it, not just you.

Comment: Some of the downvotes on this question are likely because you asked a duplicate on purpose, something that's very much frowned upon around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Update Panel` or use `AJAX` to get data and fill the textbox2.

Comment: try setting the `AutoPostBack` property to true `textBox1.AutoPostBack = true`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `AutoPostBack` property of the `textBox1` to `true` asblow:

```
textBox1.AutoPostBack = true;
```